# Use /proc to provide daemonized process information

Tags: c, linux

Is it possible to use /proc within a C programm to provide information about the internal state?

For example I contribute the handle `internalInfo` that a `cat /proc/2382/internalInfo` outputs me information I would otherwise have to retrieve by e.g. sending a signal to the process to generate the information into the logfile and then parse the logfile etc.

Comment: Do you mean /proc/self/stat or /proc/self/status?

Comment: Why not use any old file?

Comment: I dont know wether it should be kernel c! the idea is to have a file handle to which a cat to executes a certain method in my daemon process to output information. /proc does provide information this way, hence the idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of procfs : "providing a more convenient and standardized method for dynamically accessing process data held in the kernel" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs).

In this sense, procfs is to expose the kernel's information about a process, it is not to be used as interprocess communication in user space.

To specifically answer the question: yes, you could expose information about your process to processes using procfs -- this should only be done if the information that is needed is kept within the kernel. procfs should not be used if the information you are trying to access is maintained by the process itself in userspace -- I recommend using some other kind of communication method such as pipes, shared memory, files, or signals.